# How to wrap multiple elements around 1 larger element with responsive width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a responsive template where multiple `li` elements wrap one larger `li` element but I would like the larger element to be the same width as the current `li` elements surrounding it and also centered. This is kind of hard for me to explain so I made an example. Here is the link.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richie11/5L81avf9/1/)

```css
body,
html {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ul-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ul-list li.box {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 7px 7px 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0px 10px -4px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 99.4%;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:1904px) {
  .inner {
    width: 1681px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1694px) {
  .inner {
    width: 1467px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1482px) {
  .inner {
    width: 1258px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1268px) {
  .inner {
    width: 1045px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1074px) {
  .inner {
    width: 834px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:863px) {
  .inner {
    width: 621px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:652px) {
  .inner {
    width: 411px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:441px) {
  .inner {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-list">
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="wrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
</ul>
```

If you resize the example you will understand what I am trying to do.
In the example, I created a 100% width `li` element with class name "wrap". Since I wasn't able to center align it because of the float I created a div with the class "inner" and then just used media queries to resize so that I could at least show exactly what I am trying to do.

I am not sure of a good way to get the same sort of functionality as I show in the example. Does anyone have any ideas?
I would prefer a CSS solution but I am open to using a javascript or jquery solution as well if needed. Browser compatibility is pretty important but I am not really worried about very outdated Internet Explorer browsers etc. Thanks.

EDIT:

Some people are not understanding what I am trying to do so here are some pics.

With a regular floated element you can't center it and I want a box that is placed after the first list element that can be resized and centered to match the outside wrapping boxes depending on screen width. With a regular float you get this if your screen size is only large enough for 3 boxes.

[image: regular floated element 1]

Or you get this on a larger screen that will fit 5 boxes.
[image: regular floated element 2]

Which look pretty ugly.

What I am trying to do is match the widths of the wrapping list elements and also center the blue box so that everything looks equal like this.

[image: better looking boxes1]

[image: better looking boxes2]

Comment: Reading your description, I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but would using CSS `grid` or `flex-box` models work for you?

Comment: I seen some examples using flex to create grids and stuff but the floated style element I am trying to create is what throws me off because I want it responsive in width to match the outer elements. For example if there are only 3 elements in width due to a small screen size then I want the larger element to match the width of the 3 elements and cenetered with them as well. It just looks better that way when everything is the same width.

Comment: if you want equal width, why do you set different width in media query?

Comment: the elelemnt "wrap" is floating with a width of 100%. Since it cannot be centered I created the div "inner" inside wrap to use as the visibile larger element since it can be resized and centered. I used media queries on the blue div to match the width of the boxes depending on screen size so if there are 3 boxes in width showing and they are 200px then the blue box should be around 600px in width to match. The blue box floats after the first list element to allow wrapping of all list elelements around it depending on screen size.

Comment: Its very difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish here.When you use the term "wrap" and "wrapping" here, what do you mean? Normally, "wrapping" refers to when 1 HTML element is nested inside another element. So in this code: `<li class="wrap"><div class="inner"></div></li>` the `li` is wrapping the `div`. You keep mentioning `li`'s wrapping other `li`'s but I don't see that anywhere in your code. Do you mean "wrapping" like as in text wrapping to a new line?

Comment: Please look at my edit.